# Why my data is not refresh after adding a new project. The PrimeNg Dialog also not close. Please advice me to improve

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

Every Time when I add new project The dialog stay open and If I keep clicking Add the projects getting post. Once I close the dialog The new added projects are not shows until I refresh the page.
**My add-project-component.ts**

```
addProject(){
    var val ={
      id:this.id,
      projectName:this.projectName,
      clintName:this.clintName,
      initiationDate:this.initiationDate,
      duration:this.duration
    };
    this.projects.addProject(val).subscribe(res=>{
      this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary:'Service Message', detail:res.toString()});
        alert(res.toString());
    });
  }
```

HTML codes are:

```
<div class="container mt-12">
      <div class="mb-1">
        <label for="projectName">Project Name</label>
        <input pInputText class="form-control" id="projectName" [(ngModel)]="projectName" placeholder="ProjectName">
      </div><br>
      <div class="mb-1">
        <label for="clintName">Clint Name</label>
        <input pInputText class="form-control" id="clintName"  [(ngModel)]="clintName" placeholder="ClintName">
      </div><br>
      <div class="form-check mb-1">
        <label for="initiationDate">Initiation Date</label>
        <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="initiationDate" [showIcon]="true" inputId="icon"></p-calendar>
      </div><br>
      <div class="form-check mb-1">
        <label for="duration">Duration</label>
        <input pInputText class="form-control" id="duration"  [(ngModel)]="duration" placeholder="Duration">
      </div>
      <button (click)="addProject()" *ngIf="proj.id==0" class="btn btn-primary">
        Add
      </button>
  </div>
```

Please help me to solve the problem, I have seen other questions related to this issue but there were not much help.

Comment: Could you please describe how do you display the projects?

Comment: I have component project, in that component I use primeng dialog to show child component. In the html file of child I have input fields. Data show and I can add delete too but I have to refresh the page to see the changes.

Comment: Probably you're storing the state on the dialog component, so when it's closed you lose it. However, when you refresh the app it fires a new request, thus getting the updated data. Store the state in a service, outside the component, and you should be fine.